# Mapping of VBScript and .NET functions in .NET

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Currently we are doing conversion of VBScript Templates to Modular Templates as a part of upgrade from SDL Tridion 5.3 to SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, but while doing so we face challenges in finding correct equivalent functions in .NET.

e.g Equivalent function of these two VBScript functions in .NET `DisplayPublishedComponentLink` and `MakeTcdlComponentLink`

Can anyone provide me info regarding the mapping of these VBScript functions in .NET?

Comment: Please add more detail and if possible give code of your existing function.

Comment: Robert Curlette seems to think that using Razor templates with Tridion provides the most direct migration path from VBscript templates. He gave some example mappings between the two here: http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/wiki/VBScriptToRazorExamples . (Note that the Razor Mediator is not an SDL product, but people seem to have gotten good mileage from it)

Answer (score 9):

There is no exact mapping of the VBScript functions (used in VBScript Templates) in Modular Templating as these two template models are completely different.

When migrating a VBScript Template you should never try to just convert (or rewrite) it, but look at its requirements and build a Modular Template from scratch meeting those requirements. This might sound less efficient, but actually is not as the Modular Template model has different benefits which you will start using then.

*To give a bit more detail, in Modular Templates you are expected to separate design and functionality by using Dreamweaver TBBs and .NET Assembly TBBs, while in a VBscript Template this all was mixed.*

The functions you mention contain both functionality and design, in a Modular Template you should find they are not even required anymore. For example, you can simply use the following code in your Dreamweaver TBB:

```html
<a tridion:href="@@LinkField.ID@@">@@LinkText@@</a>
```

You might also be interested in the following articles on Modular Templating, to get a bit more detail on its concepts and how to use them:

- [The different levels of Compound Templating Part 1](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/compound_templating_part1.aspx)
- [The different levels of Compound Templating Part 2](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/compound_templating_part2.aspx)
- [Dynamic Linking in ASP.NET websites](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/dynamiclinkinginaspnetwebsites.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bart on starting from scratch. Simply duplicating everything in C# code might save a little up front, but misses the strongest features of modular templating (such as *modularity*).

When comparing old versus new templates, consider:

- Moving layout and markup generating code to DWT TBB
- Keeping track of repeated logic between VBScript templates and consider creating C# TBBs to group like-functionality
- Finding template functionality that differs by context or hard-coded values and move these to parameters schema or C# TBB logic

If you can do the last point, you can reduce the number of templates in such a conversion while creating useful and re-usable template building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

When moving from the old legacy templates to modular templating, then only do this when you are implementing a new design of your website. And if possible you can then at the same time rethink the entire architecture (publishing model) of your website solution.

From a technical perspective there are sure benefits in the move to modular templating, and because the legacy templates are depricated, in terms of support for sure.

But i'm sure you would like to get a bit more bang for your $$.